# ¿Cómo agregar más de una lista desplegable (combobox) en un formulario en laravel 10.40.0?

Tags: php, laravel

Estoy implementando un CRUD con Laravel 10.40.0, con varias tablas y tengo tablas (detalle) que tienen las llaves foráneas (FK) de otras tablas. Al elaborar el formulario en *create.blade.php*, se incluye el foreach para cada fk, sin embargo, al visualizar el formulario muestra error:

> "message": "Variable indefinida $tipoinvestigacion

a partir de la variable de la segunda lista desplegable.

En el controlador, se tiene la función *crear*, donde se retorna las 7 listas desplegables de las FK:

```
public function create()
     {
     $linea = Linea::all();
     return view('dashboard.produccioncientifica.create', ['linea' => $linea]);

    $tipoinvestigacion = TipoInvestigacion::all();
    return view('dashboard.produccioncientifica.create', ['tipoinvestigacion' => $tipoinvestigacion]);

    $tipoproduccioncientifica = TipoProduccionCientifica::all();
    return view('dashboard.produccioncientifica.create', ['tipoproduccioncientifica' => $tipoproduccioncientifica]);

    $tipoparticipacion = TipoParticipacion::all();
    return view('dashboard.produccioncientifica.create', ['tipoparticipacion' => $tipoparticipacion]);

    $mediodifusion = MedioDifusion::all();
    return view('dashboard.produccioncientifica.create', ['mediodifusion' => $mediodifusion]);

    $tipofuentefinanciamiento = TipoFuenteFinanciamiento ::all();
    return view('dashboard.produccioncientifica.create', ['tipofuentefinanciamiento' => $tipofuentefinanciamiento]);

    $investigador = Investigador ::all();
    return view('dashboard.produccioncientifica.create', ['investigador' => $investigador]);

    }
```

Lo que espero es un formulario con las listas desplegables que permiten seleccionar datos en el comboBox de las 7 tablas que van a alimentar de datos a la tabla *Produccioncientifica*:

```
$linea = Linea::all();
    
$tipoinvestigacion = TipoInvestigacion::all();
    
$tipoproduccioncientifica = TipoProduccionCientifica::all();
    
$tipoparticipacion = TipoParticipacion::all();
    
$mediodifusion = MedioDifusion::all();

$tipofuentefinanciamiento = TipoFuenteFinanciamiento ::all();
$investigador = Investigador ::all();
```

Comment: Ten en cuenta que al poner un `return` termina el prociso de la función. Tendrías que ponerlo al final con todas las varisbles juntas

Answer (score 0):

Tú error se da porque la variable nunca es mandada a la vista, esto dado por el primer `return` (todo lo que está después de este no se ejecuta).

También te recomiendo usar `compact` para pasar data a tus vistas.

```
public function create()
{
    $linea = Linea::all();
    $tipoinvestigacion = TipoInvestigacion::all();
    $tipoproduccioncientifica = TipoProduccionCientifica::all();
    $tipoparticipacion = TipoParticipacion::all();
    $mediodifusion = MedioDifusion::all();
    $tipofuentefinanciamiento = TipoFuenteFinanciamiento ::all();
    $investigador = Investigador ::all();

    return view(
        'dashboard.produccioncientifica.create',
         compact(
             'linea',
             'tipoinvestigacion',
             'tipoproduccioncientifica',
             'tipoparticipacion',
             'mediodifusion',
             'tipofuentefinanciamiento',
             'investigador'
         )
    );

}
```